# Numpy - create matrix with rows of vector

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have a vector `[x,y,z,q]` and I want to create a matrix:

```
[[x,y,z,q],
 [x,y,z,q],
 [x,y,z,q],
...
 [x,y,z,q]]
```

with m rows. I think this could be done in some smart way, using broadcasting, but I can only think of doing it with a for loop.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Certainly possible with [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) after adding with `m` zeros along the columns, like so -

```
np.zeros((m,1),dtype=vector.dtype) + vector
```

Now, NumPy already has an in-built function [`np.tile`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) for exactly that same task -

```
np.tile(vector,(m,1))
```

Sample run -

```
In [496]: vector
Out[496]: array([4, 5, 8, 2])

In [497]: m = 5

In [498]: np.zeros((m,1),dtype=vector.dtype) + vector
Out[498]: 
array([[4, 5, 8, 2],
       [4, 5, 8, 2],
       [4, 5, 8, 2],
       [4, 5, 8, 2],
       [4, 5, 8, 2]])

In [499]: np.tile(vector,(m,1))
Out[499]: 
array([[4, 5, 8, 2],
       [4, 5, 8, 2],
       [4, 5, 8, 2],
       [4, 5, 8, 2],
       [4, 5, 8, 2]])
```

You can also use [`np.repeat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) after extending its dimension with `np.newaxis/None` for the same effect, like so -

```
In [510]: np.repeat(vector[None],m,axis=0)
Out[510]: 
array([[4, 5, 8, 2],
       [4, 5, 8, 2],
       [4, 5, 8, 2],
       [4, 5, 8, 2],
       [4, 5, 8, 2]])
```

You can also use [`integer array indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) to get the replications, like so -

```
In [525]: vector[None][np.zeros(m,dtype=int)]
Out[525]: 
array([[4, 5, 8, 2],
       [4, 5, 8, 2],
       [4, 5, 8, 2],
       [4, 5, 8, 2],
       [4, 5, 8, 2]])
```

And finally with [`np.broadcast_to`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html), you can simply create a `2D` view into the input `vector` and as such this would be virtually free and with no extra memory requirement. So, we would simply do -

```
In [22]: np.broadcast_to(vector,(m,len(vector)))
Out[22]: 
array([[4, 5, 8, 2],
       [4, 5, 8, 2],
       [4, 5, 8, 2],
       [4, 5, 8, 2],
       [4, 5, 8, 2]])
```

---

Runtime test -

Here's a quick runtime test comparing the various approaches -

```
In [12]: vector = np.random.rand(10000)

In [13]: m = 10000

In [14]: %timeit np.broadcast_to(vector,(m,len(vector)))
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.4 µs per loop # virtually free!

In [15]: %timeit np.zeros((m,1),dtype=vector.dtype) + vector
10 loops, best of 3: 95.1 ms per loop

In [16]: %timeit np.tile(vector,(m,1))
10 loops, best of 3: 89.7 ms per loop

In [17]: %timeit np.repeat(vector[None],m,axis=0)
10 loops, best of 3: 86.2 ms per loop

In [18]: %timeit vector[None][np.zeros(m,dtype=int)]
10 loops, best of 3: 89.8 ms per loop
```