# create indices with numpy for zeros and ones

Tags: python, numpy

I wish to create a numpy array of shape,

(205, 2) and it should look something like this for each tensor [1,0] x 205 times.

I tried to use `np.ones([205,2])`. However, the value is [1,1] for 205 times and not [1,0] for 205 times.

I am new to programming and would like to seek help from all big seniors here. I am just a baby programmer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numpy - create matrix with rows of vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33200625/numpy-create-matrix-with-rows-of-vector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a better way (there is always a better way!), but here's what comes to my mind:

```
a = np.ones((205, 2)) - np.array((0, 1))
```

Alternatively:

```
a = np.ones((205, 2))
a[:, 1] = 0
```

Or:

```
a = np.zeros((205, 2))
a[:, 0] = 1
```

**The latter two solutions are the fastest.**

Comment: The last one is the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

And another way using `np.tile()`:

```
np.tile([1,0], (205,1))
```

See [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html).

Yet another way is to use `np.broadcast_to()`:

```
np.broadcast_to([1,0], (205, 2))
```

See [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html#numpy.broadcast_to).

Edit:[DYZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4492932/dyz)'s solution using `np.zeros()` followed by the assignment of `1` to the other section seems to be the fastest solution here.