# can I assign a 3d vector to a 2d matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vector

if I have a 2D matrix, and I want to assign a vector [1,1,1] into each cell of my M matrix

```
vector = np.array([1,1,1])
M= np.zeros((4,4)).astype(np.object)
M[:]=vector.astype(object)
```

This will obviously give me the error that:

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2) into shape (3,3)

So is there any method I can store my 3d vector into each cell of my 4x4 M matrix?

Thanks!

I know that if I iterate the ndarray I can do it

```
for i in range(np.shape(M)[0]):
    for j in range(np.shape(M)[1]):
        M[i][j]=vector
```

just wandering whether there's a simple syntax for this

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare what the entries of your matrix should contain with the argument `dtype`, namely `vector.dtype`.

This link might help: [Numpy - create matrix with rows of vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33200625/numpy-create-matrix-with-rows-of-vector)